# flask pytest test function that uses g

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

I'm building my testing off of [Flask Cookiecutter](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/tests/conftest.py), and all my other tests work fine. I only have problems when I test a function that uses a `g` element, such as `g.user` in my views.py file.

My `conftest.py` is exactly the same as flask-cookiecutter's plus this addition from [the faking resources and context trick](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/#faking-resources-and-context) from Flask-Testing.

```
### conftest.py ###
...
from contextlib import contextmanager
from flask import appcontext_pushed, g

@contextmanager
def user_set(app, user):
    def handler(sender, **kwargs):
        g.user = user

    with appcontext_pushed.connected_to(handler, app):
        yield
...
```

Here is my test file:

```
### test_file.py ###
from .conftest import user_set
import pytest
from my_app.utils import presave_posted_settings # <-- fn I want to test

@pytest.fixture()
def form_data():
    return {...bunch of data..}

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("form_data")
class TestPresaveSettings:
    """Test cases for checking attributes before saving"""
    def test_presave_posted_settings(self, form_data, user, testapp):
        """User meals are selected in form"""
        with user_set(testapp, user):  #<-- testapp and user available from flask-cookiecutter conftest.py
            assert presave_posted_settings(form_data)
```

When I run the test on `test_file.py`, I see:

```
user = <User 'user0'>, testapp = <webtest.app.TestApp object at 0x1101ee160>

def test_presave_posted_settings(self, form_data, user, testapp):
    """User meals are selected in form"""
    with user_set(testapp, user):
>           assert presave_posted_settings(form_data)

test_utils.py:20: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  
../my_app/utils.py:26: in presave_posted_settings
g.user.breakfast = g.user.lunch = g.user.dinner = g.user.snack = g.user.dessert = False
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  
 self = <flask.g of 'my_app'>, name = 'user'

 def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name == '__members__':
        return dir(self._get_current_object())
>       return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
E       AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user'
```

I've googled and most examples use Unittest or have all the pytest tests in one file. I'd like to stick with the pattern of having multiple test files, each taking advantage of the `conftest.py`, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to set it up so I can test functions that use the `g` element. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old, but is the most relevant to the issue I had, which I have a simple solution for.

Given a fixture for the test client like so (forgive mild pseudo-code):

```
@pytest.fixture()
def test_client():
    app = create_app()
    with app.test_client() as test_client:
        with app.app_context():
            yield test_client
```

I tried just creating a fixture that modifies g, `def modify_g(test_client)` thinking that being dependent on the context provided by `test_client` this would make it available. Due to something I might not completely understand regarding how pytest evaluates fixtures, this is not the case. You get the same `'_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute` error. However if you make an intermediate function it evaluates correctly, and the modified `g` object will be present in the testing context.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def pre_test_client():
    app = create_app()
    with app.test_client() as test_client:
        with app.app_context():
            yield test_client

@pytest.fixture()
def test_client(pre_test_client):
    yield pre_test_client

@pytest.fixture()
def modify_g(pre_test_client):
    g.user = 'test'
```

Then a test using g will work, if defined:

```
def test_g_data(test_client, modify_g):
```

Which means it's super easy to mock a lot of different states in g data and drop them into test functions as fixtures.

I admittedly don't understand exactly why this is necessary, so I would appreciate any elucidation on how pytest evaluates the fixtures.

Note this ignores the `appcontext_pushed` solution as provided by Flask, but is a pretty quick and easy way to get it to work, though probably not an optimal solution.